# How to parse a file that looks like JSON but which is not

Tags: python, json, parse-error, jsonparser

I am trying to parse a file (filename.inc) in python which looks like:

```
a: 2: {
    s: 3: "somestuff";
    a: 14: {
        i: 601600;
        a: 6: {
            i: 559;
            a: 4: {
                s: 5: "label";
                s: 3: "somelabel";
                s: 2: "id";
                s: 3: "559";
                s: 10: "timestart";
                s: 16: "01 01 1970 00:00";
                s: 8: "timestop";
                s: 16: "24 01 2020 20:55";
            }
            i: 18158;
            a: 4: {
                s: 5: "label";
                s: 12: "someotherlabel";
                s: 2: "id";
                s: 5: "18158";
                s: 10: "timestart";
                s: 16: "01 01 1970 00:00";
                s: 8: "timestop";
                s: 16: "25 01 2020 18:55";
            }
            i: 10402;
            a: 4: {
                s: 5: "label";
                s: 3: "newlabel";
                s: 2: "id";
                s: 5: "10402";
                s: 10: "timestart";
                s: 16: "01 01 1970 00:00";
                s: 8: "timestop";
                s: 16: "26 01 2020 06:55";
            }
```

and so on...
I tried to use :

```
import json

with open('filename.inc') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

but got:
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

I tried to remove the first colon, to add quotes, to replace semicolon by coma:

```
"a2": {
    "s3": "somestuff",
    "a14": {
        "i": 601600,
        "a6": {
            "i": 559,
            "a4": {
                "s5": "label",
                "s3": "somelabel",
                "s2": "id",
                "s3": "559",
                "s10": "timestart",
                "s16": "01 01 1970 00:00",
                "s8": "timestop",
                "s16": "24 01 2020 20:55",
            }
            "i": 18158,
            "a4": {
                "s5": "label",
                "s12": "someotherlabel",
                "s2": "id",
                "s5": "18158",
                "s10": "timestart",
                "s16": "01 01 1970 00:00",
                "s8": "timestop",
                "s16": "25 01 2020 18:55",
            }
            "i": 10402,
            "a4": {
                "s5": "label",
                "s3": "newlabel",
                "s2": "id",
                "s5": "10402",
                "s10": "timestart",
                "s16": "01 01 1970 00:00",
                "s8": "timestop",
                "s16": "26 01 2020 06:55",
            }
```

but that gives me multiple keys with same id...
Thinking of turning that into an html file with tags, to parse with beautifulsoup, but it seems too complex for such a file.
I would appreciate any hint, thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like PHP `serialize` output, but prettified. Try to see if [phpserialize](https://pypi.org/project/phpserialize/) will work on it. I don't know if extra spaces hurt or not, you might need to unprettify in first.

Comment: Definitely not JSON, nor Python dict. Could you tell us where that come from? Or you should try to find and understand how it was generated, this may help you to know how to parse it.

Comment: @Amadan, I must admitt I did prettify it myself, to make it more easily readable ^^
At first, the file was:
a:2:{s:3:"somestuff";a:14:{i:601600;a:6:{i:559;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:3:"somelabel";s:2:"id";s:3:"559";s:10:"timestart";s:16:"0101197000:00";s:8:"timestop";s:16:"2401202020:55";}i:18158;a:4:{s:5:"label"

Comment: In that case, `phpserialize.loads(source)` (where `source` is a bytestring) should work.

Comment: @BastienAntoine actually, it is a file which is updated every hour and I think it has something to do with an SQLite importation, but not sure. Cannot really tell where that comes from, but all I can say is that I need to parse it ;)
Thanks for your time

Comment: @Amadan : even if I only code in Python? Thanks for your time

Comment: The format is PHP's. `phpserialize` that I linked to before is a Python library to parse and generate that format.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan! I will try that :)

Answer (score 0):

I checked, and spaces hurt both PHP's native `serialize` as well as Python phpserialize. The "sanitisation" you performed makes it into an invalid dump anyway (e.g. `s: 3: "somestuff"` is illegal, it encodes 3-character string "somestuff", where "somestuff" is clearly not 3 characters long), so I'll have to construct my own example:

```
source = """
a: 2: {
    i: 0;
    s: 3: "foo";
    i: 1;
    s: 4: "quux";
};
"""

import re
import phpserialize     # requires: pip install phpserialize

cleanup_re = re.compile('(".*?")|\s+')
clean_source = cleanup_re.sub(lambda m: m.group(0) if m.group(1) else "", source)
data = phpserialize.loads(bytes(clean_source, 'utf8'))
```

This will only work if no strings have double quotes in them; I can't think of a way to do this without writing a proper parser.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Amadan !!
Actually you are right, the real somestuff label was 3 characters long, I did not know this numer after s: was the number of characters!
And no strings have double quotes in them, so that should work, can't wait to try it! Thanks!!! :)

Comment: As I said in the comments to the question, if you don't have the prettified version, just the last line should suffice. The rest is just to undo the extra spaces.

Comment: Yup: `s:3:"foo";` is the 3-character string `"foo"`, `i:10402;` is the integer `10402`, `d:3.2` is a double (`4.2`), and `a:2:{...};` is a 2-element array (you should have 4 entries inside the curlies, as key-value-key-value), though PHP "arrays" behave as both dicts and lists in Python, and so `phpserialize` will always just turn them into dicts.

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks! I marked your answer as useful, but I have not enough "reputation points" to make it count ;)
Just one thing: when I print the data from your code, it gives: {0: b'foo', 1: b'quux'}, how can I get rid of "b" and just keep {0: 'foo', 1: 'quux'}?